# Directory is not reading properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having One Directory

C:\Kuldeep\kverma\kver\

After that It consists thousands of Folders with Different name .Each Folder consists Different Excel File . I need to read Each Files from Different Folders .

I want To read All The Folders Path from C:\Kuldeep\kverma\kver\ Folder.

I used below code for getting the folders name with path ..

```
        string path = @"C:\Kuldeep\kverma\kver\";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        Console.WriteLine("File Name Size Creation Date and Time");
                                                                                                   Console.WriteLine("========");

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dirinfo in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            String name = dirinfo.Name;
            String pth = dirinfo.FullName;
            Console.WriteLine( name, pth);
       }
```

Total 10700 folders are there in C:\Kuldeep\kverma\kver\ Directory But It is reading only 54 Folder..

Please provide me any solution for Reading Folder name and location Also Reading File from Each Folder in Single Shot .

Answer (score 1):

You should put a try catch around the GetDirectories call to handle the exceptions in the below post.

That might give you a clue as to why it is not enumerating properly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try a recursive approach:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;

    class Program
    {
        public static IList<DirectoryInfo> dirs;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dirs = new List<DirectoryInfo>();

            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\tmp");

            GetDirs(dir);
            Console.WriteLine(dirs.Count);
        }

        public static void GetDirs(DirectoryInfo root)
        {
            foreach (var directoryInfo in root.GetDirectories())
            {
                dirs.Add(directoryInfo);
                GetDirs(directoryInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm not sure what hidden dangers might be lurking because of this (Stack overflow exceptions, access denied?) so I'd recommend placing a `try..catch` block in the `foreach` loop to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the contents of every sub directory:

```
// Flatten out the directory structure in to a string array.
var directoryList = Directory.GetDirectories("<<RootPath>>", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var directory in directoryList)
{
  DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
}
```

edited with the questions code updated:

```
    string path = @"C:\Kuldeep\kverma\kver\";
    string[] directoryArray = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var directory in directoryArray)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        String name = dirinfo.Name;
        String pth = dirinfo.FullName;
        Console.WriteLine(name, pth);
    }
```

Comment: I think this didn't come in until .net 2.0 by the way so if you're using 1.1 (yuk!) go for the recursive answer :)